# SQL Query to update fields multiple times

Tags: sql, wordpress, migration

I want to migrate an old joomla website to wordpress.
I used the plugin "FG Joomla to WordPress" and in general it did its job well.

Problem is that the joomla installation used a image gallery called "Morfeoshow" that was included in the posts content (e.g. {morfeo 401}). Of course those pictures didnt get imported, but tag that was used for adding the gallery.
I transfered all the photos to the new FTP and also migrated the database tables i need to identify a picture.
Further i only have access to the FTP and a phpmyadmin interface.

I tried solving my problem with SQL. This does work partly.
The result is that posts with a Morfeo Gallery Tag get the correct photo attached, but it only works with the first photo, then it stops for a post and continues to the next.
If executed again it of course attaches the same photo again.

My query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts

INNER JOIN jos_morfeoshow ON wp_posts.post_title = jos_morfeoshow.name
INNER JOIN jos_morfeoshow_img ON jos_morfeoshow.id = jos_morfeoshow_img.gallery_id

SET wp_posts.post_content = CONCAT(post_content, '<p><img class="joomla_import_photo" src="/wordpress/morfeo/',jos_morfeoshow.folder,'/big/',jos_morfeoshow_img.filename,'"></p>')
WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%morfeo%'
```

Is there a way to write the query so it adds all photos that belong to a post?

Comment: might be worth posting the php around this query so we can see whats going on. It sounds like an array isnt working quite right when you are inserting the values, but without the code we can't really check

Comment: no php code to post, this is the query i execute in the phpmyadmin backend

Comment: thats the column name of the table jos_morfeoshow where the folder name is stored

Comment: i would advise running a query attempting to select all the elements you expect to be updated into the table, and comparing that with the expected output. Run that same query, but replace `UPDATE` with `SELECT` and drop the `SET` line

Comment: tried it that way and finished the migration. thx for the tip

Comment: I recommend posting your final solution as an answer so that this question can be flagged as answered